# Float layout won't cover all screen

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make a float layout using CSS with the following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type'text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="authentification">
        <h1>authentification</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="cart">
        <h1>cart</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>content</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <h1>footer</h1>
    </div>


</body>
```

And the associated CSS code:

```
#header
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #EAE5DF;
    width: 80%;
    height: 175px;
}


#authentification
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: #8A5D1D;
    float: right;
}

#cart
{
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #861825;
    float: right;
}


#content
{
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #EAE5DF;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #8A5D1D;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Now the problem is that the code above displays the the divs as they are meant to be display but however leaves a blank space at the bottom.

What I am trying to do is figure out how to get rid of the white space by:
1) Having footer at the bottom of the page
2) when the div 'content' or 'cart' gets more element than the other, both of them should be the same height of course.

I'd appreciate help.

Comment: why did you set float left?

Comment: In which one? You can run the code and you will see.
Here's the actual plan:
HEAD \ AUTHENTIFICATION......
CONTENT \ CART......
FOOTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to have divs side by side it is not a good idel to do this by `float`, Instead use flex.

```css
.wrapper{display: flex;}

#authentification, #cart{width:20%; background-color: #bbb;}

#header, #content{flex: 1; background-color: #eee;}

#footer{background-color: orange;}

h1{margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height:100px;">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="authentification">
        <h1>authentification</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="height: calc(100vh - 150px);">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>content</h1>
    </div> 
    <div id="cart">
        <h1>cart</h1>
    </div>               
</div>
<div id="footer" style="height: 50px;">
     <h1>footer</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact I just tried the code but it also doesn't work. As the Cart is supposed to be onto the right of content. And the white space under should also not exist

Comment: use css properties box size border box also make default margin to zero of body.and others attributes

Comment: Yeah I did. Actually like I said the cart section should be under authentification and to the right of content. When I eecute the snippet I see cart right under header. 
One more thing is that when you run the code on a real page (not snippet) you end up with a lot of white space in the booom of the page.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I am trying here to cover that white space when the content is little (because this is going to be filled with php afterwards) And I need the white space the disappear. You see what I mean?

Comment: Yes Finally i found what you mean. For your future questions,  If you create a code snippet you will get faster and more accurate answers. If you want fill you page ?? you must extend one or both of  `wrapper` divs. set height for them. you can set fixed height or by percentage or dynamic height by css `calc` function.

Comment: I want it to fill the white if the content is less than the window but still work with min-height

Comment: How do what?? Create snippet or set height for divs??

Comment: No, delete the white space under through altering height

Comment: I changed my code to fill all of the page. Sorry that had a problem, I fixed that.